# codeigniter - gantt report from mysql table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, foreach, timeline, gantt-chart

i'd like to generate some gantt-report (inside html table) with data from mysql table to my ci-view..
the view should be like this :

```
| name  | week#1 | week#2 | week#3 | week#4 |

| wawan |    200 |    340 |      0 |    100 |

| wewe  |    210 |    340 |    120 |    100 |

| elias |    200 |    360 |      0 |    170 |
```

- weeks are distinct from field 'week'.
- names are distinct from field 'user'.
- numbers are sum(qtyfield) from table where user is 'name' during x week

i've tried this method, but the numbers (sum of 'qty' field) won't show :

1. fetch the weeks row to a table-header block inside a foreach loops -> done.
2. fetch the names row to a table-row block inside a foreach loops -> done.
3. the sum(qty) is query base on name in table-row and week in table-header -> ?

any idea how to do this? syntax help or just logic thought are appreciated..
thanks in advance..

Comment: are you asking how to get the sum from your database, or how to pass the name/week to the query, or what? I'm not sure what you need here.

Comment: it is how to pass the name/week to the query.. because if i try to make a query inside loops (let say with 4 weeks and 1000 names) it will makes 4000 query?